# is there any option to access the first digit of negative integer

Tags: python, list, types, integer, solution

Having crossed the three-headed faun, Harry, Dumbledore, and Snape went through a secret trap door in search of the Sorcerer's tomb. On the way, they passed through a room and found that the room has only one door opposite to them, and the door through which they entered shut once they entered the room. The door was very large with a four-digit number imprinted on it. When Harry and Dumbledore tried to open it by casting out spells, it didn't open. Having tried various spells, both got fed up and left the task to Snape. Snape curiously observing the room found that a statement was written on the top of the room. It was written as follows "I will be always four" “I can only be opened when you add my first and last digit and enter it” and “If you find a sign, you should not consider it” help Snape break the code and open the door so that they can save the Sorcerer's tomb.

```
a = int(input())
b = str(a)
if a>0:
    c = int(b[0])+int(b[-1])
    print(c)
if a<0:
    d = int(b[:2]) + int(b[-1])
    print(d)
```

i used this code but its not working at negative values. at the same time isdigit() function is there but i don't want to use that function

Answer (score 0):

#### You could convert the negative integers into positive

Change

```
a = int(input())
```

to

```
a = abs(int(input()))
```

#### If they are giving you leading zeros, then don't convert to an integer

Doing so will lose the leading zero.

Try

```
four_digits = input().replace("-","").replace("+","").replace(" ","")
added = int(four_digits[0]) + int(four_digits[3])
print(added)
```

Comment: a = abs(int(input()))
b = str(a)
d = int(b[0])+ int(b[-1])
print(d)
this code working perfectly in IDEL but hackerrank show two test cases failed out of 9

Comment: It is possible that they are tricking you by feeding in a leading zero? What are the test cases that are failing?

Comment: while we give a negative value as a input it gives test case fail. but it doesn't mention what is the error

Comment: See if it is catching you with the "+" sign - I have updated the code.

Comment: Remember to mark as correct! 8-)

Answer (score 0):

With your current code, you just need to make a small change: the first digit of a negative number will be at the second index after converting to a string.

```py
d = int(b[1]) + int(b[-1])
```